# How to pass a pointer from a void function to another C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, pointers

Consider the following piece of code:

```
void List::insertFront(int key)
{
    Node *tmp_node = new Node;

    tmp_node->key = key;
    tmp_node->next = head->next;
    tmp_node->prev = head;
    head->next = tmp_node;
    _size++;
}
```

This function adds an element to the beginning of a list and I want to catch the first element of the list in another function and delete it. For this purpose I have written the following piece of code:

```
bool List::getFront(int &key)
{
    if (head->next->key == key)
    {
        Node *tmp_node = new Node;

        head->next = tmp_node->next;
        delete tmp_node;
        delete head->next;
        _size--;
        return true;
    }
    else return false;
}
```

As you can see each time I am creating a new node which utilizes a fresh empty list, but I want to use the list that was created in the previous function.

How can I pass the node from `insertFront()` to `getFront()`?

Comment: `insertFront()` should update `head`. This is the starting point for the list and will be accessible in `getFront()`

Comment: The first node of the list appears to be `head->next`

Comment: this question is rather unclear. do you know that `insertFront` and `getFront` are class methods and that you can access members of the class? do you know how to return a value from a function?

Comment: Why does `getFront` create a new `Node` at all? That doesn't make any sense.

Comment: `getFront` just removes the node from the list [if a match] but it gets trashed. Is that useful? Would returning the matched node be better (e.g. `Node * List::getFront(int &key)` and just doing: `if (head->next->key == key) { Node *tmp = head->next; head->next = tmp->next; _size--; return tmp; } else return NULL;` Also, shouldn't you check `head->next` for non-null before doing `head->next->key`?

Comment: Rethink the name `getFront`. Even after you fix up the broken logic to not trash the list, it doesn't get a node.

Comment: "*`getFront` just removes the node from the list*" - no, it doesn't. If that is your intention, that is not what the code actually does.

Answer (score 0):

Your `getFront()` code is all wrong.  You need something more like this instead:

```
bool List::popFrontIfMatches(int key)
{
    Node *tmp_node = head->next;
    if ((tmp_node) && (tmp_node->key == key))
    {
        if (tmp_node->next)
            tmp_node->next->prev = tmp_node->prev;
        if (tmp_node->prev)
            tmp_node->prev->next = tmp_node->next;
        head->next = tmp_node->next;
        delete tmp_node;
        _size--;
        return true;
    }
    else
        return false;
}
```

That being said, why are you treating `head->next` as the 1st node in the list, and not `head` itself as is the usual common practice?

```
void List::insertFront(int key)
{
    Node *tmp_node = new Node;    
    tmp_node->key = key;
    tmp_node->next = head;
    tmp_node->prev = NULL;
    head = tmp_node;
    _size++;
}

bool List::popFrontIfMatches(int key)
{
    Node *tmp_node = head;
    if ((tmp_node) && (tmp_node->key == key))
    {
        if (tmp_node->next)
            tmp_node->next->prev = tmp_node->prev;
        if (tmp_node->prev)
            tmp_node->prev->next = tmp_node->next;
        head = tmp_node->next;
        delete tmp_node;
        _size--;
        return true;
    }
    else
        return false;
}
```